# linked list is crashing my program

Tags: c, string, linked-list, crash, strtok

Hello I am coding a program that accepts user input string and tokenize it and store it into a linked list. I've tested my linked list with a manual I mean word by word input without using strtok() and it works just fine maybe there is something with my strtok(). I am not sure though you may also check my implementation of my linked list.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct wordNode NODE;
struct wordNode
{
    char *word;
    char *nextWord;
    NODE *next;
};

NODE *head = NULL;
NODE *tail = NULL;

NODE* createList(char*, char*);
NODE* addToList(char*, char*);
void printList(void);

int main(void)
{
    char input[2048];
    char *userWord, *firstWord, *nextWord;

    gets(input);

    userWord = strtok(input, " .,!?;:");

    while(userWord != NULL)
    {
        firstWord = userWord;
        userWord = strtok(NULL, " .,!?;:");
        nextWord = userWord;
        addToList(firstWord, nextWord);
     }

    printList();

    return 0;
}

NODE* createList(char* word, char* nextWord)
{
    NODE *ptr = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        /*node creation failde*/
        return NULL;
    }

    ptr->word = malloc((strlen(word) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    ptr->nextWord = malloc((strlen(nextWord) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    ptr->word = strdup(word);
    ptr->word = strdup(nextWord);
    ptr->next = NULL;

    head = tail = ptr;

    return ptr;
}

NODE* addToList(char* word, char* nextWord)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return createList(word, nextWord);
    }

    NODE *ptr = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        /*node creation failed*/
        return NULL;
    }

    ptr->word = malloc((strlen(word) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    ptr->nextWord = malloc((strlen(nextWord) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    ptr->word = strdup(word);
    ptr->word = strdup(nextWord);
    ptr->next = NULL;

    tail->next = ptr;
    tail = ptr;

    return ptr;
}

void printList(void)
{
    NODE *ptr = head;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
         printf("\n--%s----%s--\n", ptr->word, ptr->nextWord);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: i checked it again I think its because of my linked list impelmentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is too. Please give us more information rather than just "it crashed". For example, have you narrowed down where the crash is likely to be? Use of a debugger would tell you that info almost immediately.

Comment: if you use `strdup` you don't need to `malloc` beforehand, it would only leak memory

Comment: @AlanAu hmmmm i am not familiar with debugger since im still a student but i tried putting printing out the strtok() part and commenting out the addToList part that goes like this:

while(userWord != NULL)
    {
        firstWord = userWord;
        userWord = strtok(NULL, " .,!?;:");
        nextWord = userWord;
        printf("\n\n%s------%s\n", firstWord, nextWord);
        //addToList(firstWord, nextWord);
     }

and it works fine so I think its because of my linked list.

Comment: @Diego hi I tried commenting out the mallocs and it didnt crash anymore but it stores some random special chars

Comment: Well, now is a good time to learn to use the debugger. Your code has quite a few problems so it's hard to tell you which of them exactly is causing the crash (you need to fix all of them). Here's one potential: You malloc `ptr->nextword` but you never initialised the contents of the malloced memory. Then you try to print it with `printf`. This is likely to cause a buffer overflow depending on what garbage happens to be in the buffer.

Comment: I suspect this `ptr->word = strdup(nextWord);` is supposed to be this `ptr->nextword = strdup(nextWord);`. And of course remove the mallocs for these`word` and `nextword` buffers as strdup already gives you a new buffer.

Comment: Yes thanks for your help you two... my code is working perfectly now. have a nice day ahead :) I just removed the string malloc part and I noticed I've put nothing on the *nextWord pointer that is why it is just printing random special chars.

Comment: yes that was Im talking about @AlanAu. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the string malloc part and I noticed I've put nothing on the *nextWord pointer that is why it is just printing random special chars.

```
NODE* createList(char* word, char* nextWord)
{
    NODE *ptr = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
         /*node creation failde*/
        return NULL;
     }

    //ptr->word = malloc((strlen(word) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    //ptr->nextWord = malloc((strlen(nextWord) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    ptr->word = strdup(word);
    ptr->nextWord = strdup(nextWord);
    ptr->next = NULL;

    head = tail = ptr;

    return ptr;
}

NODE* addToList(char* word, char* nextWord)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return createList(word, nextWord);
    }

    NODE *ptr = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        /*node creation failed*/
        return NULL;
    }

    //ptr->word = malloc((strlen(word) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    //ptr->nextWord = malloc((strlen(nextWord) + 1)*sizeof(char));
    ptr->word = strdup(word);
    ptr->nextWord = strdup(nextWord);
    ptr->next = NULL;

    tail->next = ptr;
    tail = ptr;

    return ptr;
}
```